# Drawing a GeoJSON with D3js on OpenLayers 4

Tags: openlayers, geojson, d3

The goal is to interact with the DOM based on users input using JavaScript. I have now considered using D3js (v5) to draw the points. Without the base vector layers (loaded as a geojson) and OpenLayers, the data gets drawn with D3js but when put together I do not see it on. Below is my code.

For JavaScript files

```
    var width = 800,
    height = 800;
var svg = d3.select("#map")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var files = ['../data/mines.geojson', "../data/mines_centroid.geojson"];

var promises = [];

files.forEach(function (url) {
    promises.push(d3.json(url))
});

Promise.all(promises).then(function (val) {
    drawMap(val[0], val[1])
});

var projection = d3.geoMercator();

var geoPath = d3.geoPath()
    .projection(projection);

var radius = d3.scaleLog();

function drawMap(mines, centroid) {
    projection.center([22.9696994071445, 40.8135651828386]);
    projection.fitSize([width, height], mines);
    svg.append("g")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(mines.features)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", geoPath)
        .attr("stroke", "blue")
        .attr("fill", "white")
        .attr("class", "mines");
    addCentroid(centroid)
}

function addCentroid(centroid) {
    console.log(centroid)

    var points = svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(centroid.features, function (d) {
            return d;
        })
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr('r', function (d) {
            return radius(d.properties.Scale) * 1.5
        })
        .attr('cx', function (d) {
            return projection(d.geometry.coordinates)[0]
        })
        .attr('cy', function (d) {
            return projection(d.geometry.coordinates)[1]
        })
        .attr("class", "centroid")
        .attr("id", function (d) {
            return d.properties.ID
        })


}
```

My GeoJSON looks like this.

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
      "name": "EPSG:4326"
    }
  },
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 1,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          22.9696994071445,
          40.8135651828386
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "FID": 1,
        "OBJECTID": 119,
        "ID": "GR-4291",
        "Code_12": "131",
        "Remark": " ",
        "Scale": 10,
        "Area_ha": 95.6086248776,
        "Shape_Leng": 6533.9468799,
        "code00": 13,
        "Shape_Le_1": 6533.9468799,
        "Shape_Area": 956086.248776,
        "ORIG_FID": 0
      }
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible code example, preferably in some code playground like [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)? Can be fake data.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bayoishola20/wj9myu0o/28/. The JS code in my original post was stored in another file and linked as "centroid.js". Not sure how to do that on fiddle. Thank you!

Comment: You will have to include some example data. Maybe http://plnkr.co/edit/ is more suitable in this case (it let's you add an arbitrary number of files).

Comment: Thank you, Stefan. Here it is now. [online code](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ho1IjJDZCxFAKUIcavAt?p=preview)

Comment: Okay, I see an orange polygon on a Greek peninsula. What should the result look like?

Comment: I would like to have the point features (mines_centroid.geojson) drawn into the polygon features (mines.geojson) using D3js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixing some minor issues in your code makes the example work. Some of them were:

1. Linking d3js v5 instead of v3.
2. Making the svg position absolute on the same position as the map.

Here is the [cleaned up code](https://blockbuilder.org/geraldo/018b487bc29bbb5dc4d7e3e8177103a1) showing your features on the map.

[image]